# Accessing allocated memory byte by byte allocated by malloc c++

Tags: c++, malloc, byte, dynamic-memory-allocation

is there's a way in C++ to access the dynamically allocated memory space byte by byte regardless of the size of this memory

Comment: you can access the memory byte-wise (this is what char pointers are good for). but what do you mean by *"regardless of the size of this memory"*? you know you shouldn't be accessing memory before or after the allocated block.

Comment: I need to create a data type that has twice the size as double

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you use a `char`-pointer for that, which is guaranteed to be able to address all contiguous bytes.

You shouldn't read out of allocated bounds, however, which could crash your program runtime or even the OS, depending on the OS.

Anyways: With a probability towards 1, this is not what you want.